# How to solve error'1004' in vba when import outlook mail to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am newbie in using VBA I suppose that I want to automate export data from outlook mail and import to excel file xlsx as I searched for a tutorial for this and I find this tutorial https://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/get-data-from-outlook-into-excel-worksheet/
I followed these steps by creating a module as I inserted in this Module this code

```
Sub GetDataFromOutlook()
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set Folder = 
OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("SSV")

i = 1

    For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("Email_Receipt_Date").Value And 
Date <= 30 / apr / 2019 Then

    Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Subject
    Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
    Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
    Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
    Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
    Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
    Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
    Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
    Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    i = i + 1
End If

Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing




End Sub
```

and finally when I am trying to run it I found this error

Run-error '1004'
Method 'Range' of object '_Global) failed

It may be the error in excel file I have?

Comment: `Date <= 30 / apr / 2019` won't do what you think.

Comment: Did you put your code in an Excel module or in a Outlook module? it need to be on Excel side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the error is relative to your **Excel** **sheet**. It's reporting that it was unable to find those `ranges`. You have to create them on your `sheet` before launching the macro.

To create a `custom Range` you have to click on your `cell` and then edit its name, like in this picture:

[image]

---

Hope this helps.

> **Note**: `Date <= 30 / apr / 2019` will not work. Change it in `Date <= "30/04/2019"` and it will work as intended.

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing but I found the same error in these lines

        Range("Email_Subject").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Subject
        .............
so I think there's some think wrong with excel file in those cells right

Comment: No problem, have you created all the `ranges` required for the file to work? In order to work your sheet needs to have these `Ranges`: `"email_Subject"`, `"email_Date"`, `"email_Sender"` and `"email_Body"`.